# Add a "|" symbol while grouping a data frame by multiple columns with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pipe

I am just starting learning pandas package and have been asked to group a data frame by multiple columns ('BRANCH_NO', 'CUSTOMER_NO') since the combination of them forms a unique value in the data frame while adding a "|" symbol between the values in other columns that have the same combination of 'BRANCH_NO' and 'CUSTOMER_NO'. I wonder if I should use for loop to loop through each column to achieve this. Thanks.

```
person_in_charge_raw = pd.DataFrame({'BRANCH_NO':['123','123','123','123','124','124'], 
                                     'CUSTOMER_NO':['001', '001', '001', '001','001','001'], 
                                     'DEPARTMENT_NO':['A01','B01','C01','D01', 'A01','B01'], 
                                     'STAFF_ID':['S001','S002','S003', 'S004', 'S001', 'S002']})

final_result = pd.DataFrame({'BRANCH_NO':['123', '124'],
                             'CUSTOMER_NO':['001', '001'],
                             'DEPARMENT_NO':['A01 | B01 | C01 | D01', 'A01 | B01'],
                             'STAFF_ID':['S001 | S002 | S003 | S004', 'S001 | S002']})
```

[Here is the screenshot of the desired result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY8IX.png)

Answer (score 2):

```
g = person_in_charge_raw.groupby(['BRANCH_NO', 'CUSTOMER_NO'])
g.agg('|'.join).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I did get the desired result using pandas with version 1.4.4, but ended up grouping the headers with a "|" in between using my company's laptop where the version of panda in it is 1.0.3. I will try figuring out what went wrong lol

Comment: I think I have figured out what went wrong with my original data frame. The function ended up inserting the headers with "|" symbols in between because there were some null values in the rest of the columns.